# Triple summation verification $\sum_{1\le i\lt j\lt k}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}$

Tags: summation, solution-verification, geometric-series

I am attempting the following triple summation. It would be great if someone would verify whether what I've done is correct.

> $$\sum_{1\le i\lt j\lt k}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{1\le i\lt j\lt k}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i3^j5^k}\\&^= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i3^j}\frac{1/5^{j+1}}{4/5}\\&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\frac{1/15^{i+1}}{14/15}\\&=\frac{1}{56}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{30^{i}}=\frac{1}{56}\cdot\frac{1}{29}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @ParaKhosla: Your calculation should be revised. See my answer below. Regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks for pointing out the erroneous indexing. The question should have read the upper limit going to $\infty$, especially in the context in which this was asked, it was clear that a numerical value was required.

Comment: You're welcome. Note, that there is no context dependent interpretation. Both index regions are pretty valid, they mean just *different regions*, As it is specified in your problem $k-1$ is the upper limit which has precisely the result stated in my answer and no other solution. The accepted answer is not correct as long as you don't *change* the index region to $1\leq i<j<k<\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum+%28sum+1%2F%282%5Ei*3%5Ej*5%5Ek%29%2C+k%3D%28j%2B1%29..infinity%29%2C+j+%3D+%28i%2B1%29..infinity%29%2C+i%3D1..infinity) yields $\dfrac{1}{1624}$, sounds like you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @gt6989b: Note, your input to WA is wrong, since $k$ is not an index, but $k-1$ is an upper limit instead. Consider for instance $\sum_{0\leq i<k}q^i=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}q^i=\frac{1-q^{k}}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct but there is a easier (to remember) way to derive the result.

To simplify the sum, the first thing one should do is get rid of the "$<$" constraint among the summation indices. If you introduce index $\ell, m$ such that $j = i + \ell$ and $k = j + m$, then
the constraint $1 \le i < j < k$ simplifies to $1 \le i,\ell,m$. This will
allow you to rewrite your iterated sum as a product of geometric series:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\substack{(i,j,k)\\1 \le i < j < k}}\frac{1}{2^i 3^j 5^k}
&= \sum_{\substack{(i,j,k)\\1 \le i, \ell, m }}\frac{1}{2^i 3^{i+\ell} 5^{i+\ell + m}}
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{30^i}\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\frac{1}{15^\ell}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{5^m}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{30}}{1-\frac1{30}}\frac{\frac{1}{15}}{1-\frac{1}{15}} \frac{\frac15}{1-\frac15} = \frac{1}{29}\frac{1}{14}\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{1624}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note $k$ is not an index, but $k−1$ is an upper limit instead. Consider for instance $\sum_{0\leq i<k}q^i=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}q^i=\frac{1-q^k}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 3):

The index region of the sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq i <j<k}}\frac{1}{5^i3^j2^k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is specified by the inequality chain
\begin{align*}
1\leq i <j<k
\end{align*}
which has $1$ as lower limit and $k-1$ as upper limit. We have *two* indices $i$ and $j$, which means we can write it as double sum as shown in the evaluation below.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq i<j<k}\frac{1}{5^{i}3^j2^k}}
> &=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{i= 1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{5^{i}}\sum_{j=i+1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{3^j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{i= 1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{5^{i}}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{i+1}-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{i = 1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{5^i}\,\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3^i}-\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &= \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{15^i}- \frac{1}{2^{k+1}\,3^{k-1}}\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{5^i}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{15}-\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)^{k-1}}{1-\frac{1}{15}}\right)-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}\,3^{k-1}}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{5}-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{k-1}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{k+2}\cdot7}\left(1-\frac{1}{15^{k-2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2^{k+3 }\,3^{k-1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{5^{k-2}}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2^{k+2}\cdot7}-\frac{1}{2^{k+3}\,3^{k-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+3}\,3^{k-1}\,5^{k-2}\cdot7}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we factor out $\frac{1}{2^k}$ and reorder the double sum using another common style.
- In (3) we evaluate the inner sum using the *[finite geometric summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (4) we do a simplification and multiply out in the next line.
- In (5) we apply the finite geometric summation formula twice and do a simplification in the following lines.

---

**Notes:**

- Varying $k$ is **not admissible** since $k-1$ is an upper limit. Here $k$ is a *[free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* whereas the indices $i$ and $j$ are *bound* variables. This is different to the situation
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{1\leq i <j<k\color{blue}{<\infty}}\frac{1}{5^{i}3^j2^k}
  \end{align*}
  where $k$ is an index bound by the upper limit $\infty$ and where $k$ varies between $j$ and $\infty$.
- The result (6) is also given by *[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum+1%2F%285%5Ei*3%5Ej*2%5Ek%29%2C+j%3Di%2B1..k-1%29%2Ci%3D1..k-2&wal=header)* with input

  ```
   sum(sum 1/(5^i*3^j*2^k), j=i+1..k-1),i=1..k-2
  ```

*Hint:* You might find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but frankly it is probably just an error in notation (which should be of course  pointed out).

Comment: @user: Thanks for the upvote! :-) When looking at the complexity of the calculation a typo seems probable. Nevertheless i think its important to point at the difference of $1\leq i<j<k$ and $1\leq i<j<k\color{blue}{<\infty}$ since there seem to be too many upvotes of wrong answers without appropriate reflection.